# Javascript - Get URL being navigated to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to use JavaScript's `OnUnload()` function to find out which URL the user is navigating away to?

For example, if my code is in `page1.html`, and the user clicks a link to `http://example.com`, is there any way for JavaScript code present in `page1.html`, to retrieve the URL `"http://example.com"` and display/store it before the page unloads?

I am able to do this if I invoke a function through my link by using its `OnClick`, but I cannot find a way to do this otherwise. (I can post my code for that if needed, but it does meet my business requirement)

EDIT : This looks to be impossible, since my business requirement demands that I **do not make any change to the content of the page, excepting the adding in of a javascript file where this code is present.**

Comment: short answer is no. Unless the user did through clicking a link that belongs to your site and then you could use that as the info you are looking for

Comment: You could replace all the links in the page with a redirect system that you handle. like http://www.example.com?rd=http://example2.com

Comment: Ah thank you Dalorzo, that is what I thought as well. I am trying to build something that can track as much data from my site, and send it over to a remote server for logging. But business requirement is that I cannot change the content in any way, except to include a javascript file to the page with the necessary code :(

Comment: And can you just use Google Analytics

Comment: How does google analytics get this data ? Do they get it from the page that is being navigated to?

Comment: try adding event listener to all `<a>` tags which makes an ajax call...

Comment: You can easily do this in JavaScript; just attach a click handler to all the anchors to intercept it.

Comment: Of course it is possible. As several users said it right now, you just need to get control over all of your <a> tags and add event listeners to them.

Comment: I'm sorry I assumed that meant adding something to the <a> tags themselves, am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ignore `onBeforeUnload/onUnload`, you don't need that. You can do it with a simple click handler like this:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var destinationLink = $(this).attr('href');

    $.post('/your/analytics/url', {link:destinationLink}, function()
    {
        // Success
        window.location.href = destinationLink;
    });
});
```

This will stop any link from working until it's been submitted to your analytics so it's not ideal - you need to make sure what ever is receiving the data does so as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the current url of the clicked link.
That will allow you to call your server to do the check of the clicked url, and then redirect it.

The code bellow change the url of the clicked link only for a couple of microseconds

```js
$("a").on("click",function(e){
    // Save the current link
    var h = this.href;

    //Change the link of the current a
    this.href = "http://www.example1.com/redirect.php?url="+encodeURI(h);

    // replace the href with the original value on the next stack
    setTimeout((function(my_link){
        return function(){
            my_link.href = h;
        };
    })(this),0);
});
```

```html
<a href="http://www.example.com">my link</a>
```

Comment: Exactly where in this process can I query my server? Right before the `setTimeout` function?

Comment: I edited the code. as `www.example1.com` is your server, the query is made by the click on the link, the url will be  : `www.example1.com/redirect.php?url=http://www.example.com`, so you need to have a redirect.php page that retrieve the url param and do whatever you want (check the referrer if the link is from your website ... log it), then redirect to the url.

Comment: The `setTimeout` is only here to handle new tab click, to set the original value on the link after the click, as the page stay openned